# Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 in windows 10 MSI (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, msi

Installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 MSI.

`First Error:` Bios mode/Legacy mode: can not install ubuntu or can not access windows.

`Solution:` Reset bios mode to UEFI mode before installing ubuntu

`Second Error:` screen freezes or  UEFI enabled windows 10 failed to display Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That's the grub screen from booting the install media.  Did you remove the install media after installation?

Comment: Removing the install media does nt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Solution:

1. Use `delete`key to access bios mode
2. Disable `fast boot`.
3. keep secure boot -> `enabled`
4. select either CD DVD or USB boot option
5. `F10` to save settings
6. `Esc` to exit bios mode
7. `start` Windows 10
8. Follow general Ubuntu installation instructions: Create new partition:free space (Ex.20 GB).
9. Use `DVD iso image` or `USB` to boot Ubuntu 16.04 in windows
10. After Ubuntu installation: Restart

Error: After reboot, UEFI mode won’t display installed Ubuntu. Instead shows following:

[image]

12. Once removed install media, shows blank screen or freezes. To fix above error. Use `delete` key to access bios mode.
13. Select `UEFI Hard disk drive  BBS Priorities`

[image]

14. Select `Ubuntu` as first OS.
15. `F10` to save and `Esc` to exit
16. displays

[image]

17.Next, Select Ubuntu from the list to launch Ubuntu, and select Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1) to launch Windows 10.

Comment: It worked with my msi GF63 . Thanks mate. Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu has also installed GRUB, a boot loader. This is what's displayed in the second picture of your answer (where you selected Ubuntu as the first OS). With GRUB, you can start any of the operating systems currently installed. Selecting `Ubuntu` from that list should launch Ubuntu, and selecting `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` should launch Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04. The system was freezing on bootup. The problem was with the graphic card drivers. After installing nvidia drivers by `sudo apt install nvidia-375` the problem went away.
NOTE - This was for my particular case, for your case it can be different. Check the latest graphic drivers available before installing `nvidia-375`