# Ubuntu Live Crashes on MSI GL62 7RD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I bought an MSI GL62 from Amazon, it has a GTX 1050 2GB and 8GB of RAM. Full  specs see [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072QT88DG).

I decided to install Ubuntu on it, but as soon as I enter the "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" it crashes with a Nouveau bug and an `initramfs` bug, after some research, I managed to fix the Nouveau bug with `nomodeset`, but the initramfs problem remains:

[image: https://askubuntu.com/questions/906053/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-in-windows-10-msi-uefi]

I've already checked the MD5, I've downloaded the iso 5 times, tried elementary OS, used `rufus`, `unetbootin` and startup disk creator to make the live-usb and nothing seems to work. Also right now I have disable fast boot, secure boot, intel speedstep and am booting with UEFI with CSM.

Please help, I don't know what to do anymore. Thank you for your attention.

Edit:
1: Tried making the live-usb with etcher.io, same problem happenned.
2: Here's a photo of what happens when I don't use nomodeset (https://imgur.com/a/p1fwP)
3: I seem to be capable of installing it in a VM, maybe that hints at something?

Comment: What is your intent? Are you using this machine to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu permanently or just trying out Ubuntu? If you are going to be using it alongside Windows, what happens if you tried to fully install the OS?

Comment: I want to dual boot, though if it seems impossible just installing ubuntu and erasing windows would be enough. Well since I can't even test it I'm kind of scared of what would happen if I tried to install it.

Comment: Looking at the image it could be a USB problem. What is the USB manufacturer?

Comment: SanDisk. I just installed elementary os using it on my mother's notebook, though her notebook's specs are quite different from mine.

Comment: Try using etcher from Resin.io. It's a program a lot like rufus except it picks the drive, the image, and it does the rest for you. I sometimes have issues with drives and images not copying over completely. Etcher verifies before the job is done. https://etcher.io/

Comment: This may or may not help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/906053/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-in-windows-10-msi-uefi

Comment: WinEubuuchs2Unix I have already disabled fast boot and tried both with secure boot enabled and disabled, that did not work.

Comment: @joaogui1 Sorry about my head then. I've passed your question onto an expert and upvoted your question to bring attention to it.

Comment: Maybe it will work with some other version of Ubuntu. Different versions of Ubuntu have different versions of the linux kernel, which in turn have different versions of hardware drivers. And a different version of some hardware driver might solve your problem. Current released versions are 14.04 LTS, 16.04.1 LTS, 16.04.3 LTS, 17.10.1. You can also try the developing version 'Bionic' to be released as 18.04 LTS in April.

Comment: You find the iso files via the following links and links from them, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865 and http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds/164485/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem it's Ubuntu if you manage to install it download ukuu and update the kernel but before when GRUB appears “Install Ubuntu” then press  <kbd>e</kbd> then add  `nouveau.modeset=0`  after  `quiet splash`
See if that works. I managed to install Debian and it runs flawlessly BUT the nvidia drivers don't work in either distro.